# How can i write multiple lines in a textfile to different textboxes?

Tags: c#

What i did to write from the boxes to the txt file

```
private void save2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream myStream;
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Filter = "Textdokument|*.txt";
    sfd.FilterIndex = 1;
    sfd.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if ((myStream = sfd.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(myStream);

            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname1.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname2.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname3.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname4.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname5.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname6.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname7.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname8.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname9.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname10.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname11.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname12.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname13.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname14.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname15.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname16.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname17.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname18.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname19.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname20.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname21.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname22.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname23.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname24.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname25.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname26.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname27.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname28.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname29.Text);
            sw.WriteLine(TextBoxCardname30.Text);
            sw.Close();
            myStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Why are you writing them to different textboxes and not just the same textbox? Can you expand more upon what you are doing?

Comment: Your question does not include and actual question.  Please add.

Comment: What you need is a `List` and a `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you meant by your question is that you want to take the contents of each line of a textfile and write it to its corresponding `textbox.text`; this should work for you:

```
TextBoxCardname1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadLines("Your Text File").Skip(0).Take(1).First();
TextBoxCardname2.Text = System.IO.File.ReadLines("Your Text File").Skip(1).Take(1).First();
TextBoxCardname3.Text = System.IO.File.ReadLines("Your Text File").Skip(2).Take(1).First();

     //...etc
```

For each line you're reading, you specify how many lines you want to skip, and how many lines you want to read (ie. `Skip(1), Take (1)` means you would skip the first line in the text file, and read the second line).

If you're trying to get the textbox.text and write it to your textfile (it's kind of hard to tell from your question) This is a simple, yet messy, and labor-intensive method:

```
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Your text file");
        lines[0] = TextBoxCardname1.text);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("Your text file", lines);

        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Your text file");
        lines[1] = TextBoxCardname2.text);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("Your text file", lines);

        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Your text file");
        lines[2] = TextBoxCardname3.text);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("Your text file", lines);

    //...etc
```

This method is a very simple way to write to a certain line in a text file. `lines[3]` would denote the 4th line in the text file, since the line numbering starts at zero `[0]` (The first line in the text file).

Comment: In the future, please select an answer if you've solved your issue.